# Run a runnable JAR file in a folder / Directory with a UTF-8 style name

Tags: java, file, utf-8, jar, runnable

When I create a jar file in ordinary way like this:
C:/myFolder/program.jar
It could be run without any problem, but when I create abnormal name (UTF-8 languages) for folder like this:
C:/پوشه/program.jar
program cannot run and OS (Windows for me) says this:
Title:
Java Virtual Machine Launcher
Context:
Error: Unable to access jarFile C:/پوشه/program.jar

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the Main class entry inside `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, you're missing this `Main-Class: classname` attribute in the second JAR. See this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: Program could run in a normal directory name. But not in a directory like C:/پوشه/program.jar which has a folder with UTF-8 characters (پوشه), how we could run it? That is the question!

Comment: Nice question man, I'm able to run it from the command line but not by directly clicking it. I think there should be a configuration in JVM which will allow this. Meanwhile I'll be looking out for solution. +1

Comment: @11thdimension Thanks! Usually I'm searching for my questions but sometimes it's necessary to ask which made my questions a little hard and nice! :)

Comment: @bdshahab checkout this answer, maybe that's the case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520549/error-unable-to-access-jarfile-encoding-issue/40561718#40561718

Comment: @Valya Thanks! it works, although people always use default settings! However, exe files always run even that solution wasn't applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem could be solved by this solution:
[Error: Unable to access jarfile. Encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520549/error-unable-to-access-jarfile-encoding-issue/40561718#40561718)

However, **exe** files don't need these additional settings and those files will be execute in any case.