# IS it impossible to launch a JAR file in a path with UTF character ?

Tags: java, utf-8, jar

This a strange problem but i'll try to explain :

The client who's gonna run the software is **only allowed** to have access to **one folder** in the OS (Windows), and that folder is written with Chinese character, and the OS (windows) language is English.

We have .jar files that need to be launched from that folder, but it just can't because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660195/run-a-runnable-jar-file-in-a-folder-directory-with-a-utf-8-style-name).

Is there a way around this ? something to trick Java into thinking that this is a "proper" path or something ? btw, that .jar file don't run even when i enter the folder and manually double-click it.

**IMPORTANT:**

- we can't change the folder name
- we can't change the system language
- we can't create any folder/file outside of that Chinese folder.

Thank you

Comment: One thing you could try is run `dir /x` in the Chinese folder's parent folder. That will show you the short name of the folder (something like "ABCDEF~1"). See if you can use that for the path to your jar.

Comment: @jingx doesn't work either, Chinese characters became "squares"

Comment: Are you allowed to access the temp folder? If so create a batch file to copy the jar there and run it from there...

Comment: no, no access anywhere outside that folder

Comment: Squares are almost always a font support issue, by which you could conclude the text is probably the Chinese that it should be.